# Adding a user inputted host to a socket, while using a singleton for the socket

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I'm using a singleton to create a global socket.
When the app starts up the use is prompted to put in a code, which will be used in connecting to the host socket. How would I pass the data string from the view controller into the singleton to be used as the URL. This is how I have my singleton set up.

```
+ (SocketKeeperSingleton *) sharedInstance {

    static dispatch_once_t _once;
    static SocketKeeperSingleton *sharedSingleton = nil;


         dispatch_once(&_once, ^{
            sharedSingleton = [[SocketKeeperSingleton alloc] init];
             [sharedSingleton initSIOSocket];
             });


    return sharedSingleton;

}

-(void) initSIOSocket {

    [SIOSocket socketWithHost:@"http://localhost:8080" response:^(SIOSocket *socket) {

            self.socket = socket;

            [self.socket on:@"q_update_B" callback:^(NSArray *args) {


                NSArray *tracks = [args objectAtIndex:0];
                self.setListTracks = tracks;
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"qUpdateB" object:nil];

        }];

        [self.socket on:@"current_artist_B" callback:^(NSArray *args) {

            self.currentArtist = [args objectAtIndex:0];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"currentArtistB" object:nil];

        }];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? When the user put in data is your singleton had already been created and used?

Comment: No, because i would need to call [SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance] after I have the user's host string, since the user's inputed host string is needed for that method which creates the singleton. @Brain89

Comment: See the answer bellow. It may be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply refactor your singleton to something like this

```
+ (SocketKeeperSingleton *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t _once;
    static SocketKeeperSingleton *sharedSingleton = nil;
    dispatch_once(&_once, ^{
        sharedSingleton = [[SocketKeeperSingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedSingleton;
 }

- (void)startSIOSocketWithHost:(NSString *)sHost {
    [SIOSocket socketWithHost:sHost response:^(SIOSocket *socket) {
...
```

And then the first singleton usage after user input could be **[[SocketKeeperSingleton sharedInstance] startSIOSocketWithHost:*userInput*]**

Comment: that'll do it. Thanks!